# How to enable wordpress website locally on network and via localhost

Tags: wordpress, apache, xampp

My wordpress site works fine on my mac via localhost, using Xammp.  I want to view the site on my iPhone.  So I type in 192.168.0.2 and voila, it brings up my localhost directory.  I then click on the site in question and the content is there but no styling or images.  I realise that this is because the paths to all the resources is hardcoded into the wordpress database.  So when I am accessing the url via 192.168.0.2/mywebsitename on my iPhone, it's looking for all the resources using a base url of localhost/mywebsitename.  Localhost path doesn't exist on my iPhone, only 192.168.0.2 does.

So has anyone found a solution to this little issue?  How can I see a wordpress installation by ip address and by localhost access?

Comment: +1 It's a legitimate question, clearly articulated. Who downvoted this?

Comment: probably someone that doesn't like wordpress I reckon

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **configuring** WordPress but is probably better suited to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's not off topic in any way. If it was the tags wouldn't exist. I exclusively dev WordPress and am personally sick of the downvotes. I am looking for this same solution plz maintain this post.

Comment: I did end up going to wordpress.stackexchange and got the perfect answer, check out http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/112497/show-wordpress-locally-in-xammp-and-in-iphone-via-ip.  Not sure if this needs to be closed now.

Answer (score 2):

For this exact issue, before developing a website. You must create a domain(VirtualHost in apache)

Add the following contents in the file httpd-vhosts.conf, make sure it is included in Apache Configuration. This line ( `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` ) should be present in httpd.conf

Contents of httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost 192.168.1.26:80
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.26:80>
<Directory "e:/program files/ampps/www/mywebsite">
Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
AllowOverride All
Order deny,allow
allow from All
</Directory>
ServerName 192.168.1.26
ServerAlias 192.168.1.26
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "e:/program files/ampps/www/mywebsite/cgi-bin/"
DocumentRoot "e:/program files/ampps/www/mywebsite"
ErrorLog "E:/Program Files/ampps/apache/logs/192.168.1.26.err"
CustomLog "E:/Program Files/ampps/apache/logs/192.168.1.26.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

(Change the path, ip, etc according to your need). Now after adding the contents. **Restart Apache**. Now when you access `192.168.1.26` (in my case) from other machine in your network or your same machine. You should see the contents of `mywebsite` folder directly(or contents index.php if it has any). Now install wordpress using the ip you specified(browser should have that ip in the address bar), in my case `192.168.1.26`.

Well I use AMPPS to avoid this headache. It allows me to create domains locally. Also if I have bought a domain say `mywebsite.com` and i want to add a customized wordpress site on, I create a the domain in the AMPPS with the same name. So the URL of my live website and the local are same. :) Then I simply put the files directly on my server via FTP and obviously import the database on my server.

EDIT: BTW, [AMPPS](http://www.ampps.com) allows to install WordPress in a single click. It has simple interface where you can specify AMPPS to install the WordPress on the created Domain.

Comment: nice info re ammps, unfortunately it's not available on mac os x, which I use.

Comment: Ok. It supports 10.6, 10.7 and 10.8. Are you on 10.5 ?

Comment: No the latest.  Just from looking at the docs, it didn't mention OS X

Comment: It supports till Mountain Lion. http://ampps.com/download its written above the download button. hope it helps :)